# Database Performance and maintenance with one thousand columns.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to create a table with one thousand fields(columns) and I don't know how to handle the performance and how to maintain it please help me with suggestions.

Comment: Why do you need 1,000 columns?

Comment: To one-up @AdamWagner: I am almost positive you *don't* need 1000 columns. Describe your scenario; but I will bet you reading up on database normalisation will be a better solution.

Comment: Please don't do this.  Its one of those things that can be done, but shouldn't for lots of reasons. 1.  A normal human can't keep 1000 pieces of information in their head. 2.  SQL Server has an 8k per data row limit so you are going to use large object types and I imagine you will use 1000 varchar(max)'s and you will never be able to optimize it. 3.  Its not a database at this point, its a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

If most times most values are NULL then you should upgrade to SQL Server 2008 and use sparse columns, see [Using Sparse Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) and [Using Column Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521.aspx).

If your column values are not mostly NULL then I question the soundness of your data model.

Answer (score 0):

First things you will have to do

1. Normalize
2. Define the entities and separate out to different tables. Draw an ER diagram and
   you will get more ideas.
3. Dont exceed Table column beyond 15 if the columns are varchar or text because
   then SQL will have to store the data in different pages. If the columns are
   boolean then it can be around 30.
4. Define clustered index properly based on your data as this will optimize querying.

Since the nature of the question is without much details the answers are also generic and from a 100 feet view.

Answer (score 0):

Again, please don't do this.

Check out the [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model with respect to databases.  It will help you store a large amount of sparse attributes on an entity and doesn't make databases cry.

The basic concept is shown below

```
create table #attributes
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    attribute varchar(20),
    attribute_description varchar(max),
    attribute_type varchar(20)
)

insert into #attributes values ('Column 1','what you want to put in column 1 of 1000','string')
insert into #attributes values ('Column 2','what you want to put in column 2 of 1000','int')

create table #entity
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    whatever varchar(max)
)

insert into #entity values ('Entity1')
insert into #entity values ('Entity2')

create table #entity_attribute
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    entity_id int,
    attribute_id int,
    attribute_value varchar(max)
)


insert into #entity_attribute values (1,1,'e1value1')
insert into #entity_attribute values (1,2,'e1value2')
insert into #entity_attribute values (2,2,'e2value2')

select * 
from #entity e
join #entity_attribute ea on e.id = ea.entity_id
```

The difference between what goes in the #entity table and what goes in the #attribute table is somewhat dependent on the application but a general rule would be something that is never null and is accessed every time you need the entity, I would limit this to 10 or so items.

Let me guess this is a medical application?